# Bayes Theorem application confusion

Tags: probability

The probability of a person NOT having Lyme disease is .99793  When tested for Lyme disease there is a false positive rate of .03 and a false negative rate of .063 .... find the probability that a person has Lyme disease given that the test result is positive.

[image]

I think we are looking for $\textbf{P(A|B)}$. I am confused on how to do that. Is Bayes Theorem required?

$$ P(A|B) = \frac{P(B)P(A|B)}{???}$$

Am I correct in saying that since $P(A) = P(A&B) +P(A&B')$, then $$P(A|B) = \frac{P(B)P(A|B)}{P(B)P(A|B) + P(B')P(A|B')}$$   I think I have been thinking about this wrongly. I have to think about the total probability of A happening. Is this correct logic? That is

\textbf{ The way I thought about it was that I had to divide by the total probability that A would happen. And that is the sum of P(A&B) and P(A&B')}

EDIT: PLEASE IGNORE THE $P(A|B) = .03$ and $P(A|B') = .06$ assignment. The image was from my early scratch work.

Answer (score 1):

Given your conventions ($A \equiv$ lime disease, $A' \equiv$ not lime disease, $B \equiv$ positive test, $B' \equiv$ negative test), you're trying to find $P(A|B)$, as you correctly guessed.

Bayes Theorem states:
$$
P(A|B) = \frac{P(B|A) P(A)}{P(B)}
$$

and the law of total probability (I forget the official name) states:
$$P(B) = \sum P(B|C_i) P(C_i)$$
where the $\left\{C_i\right\}$ form a set of mutually exclusive elements that span a complete probability space. In our case that is, 
$$
P(B) = P(B|A) P(A) + P(B|A') P(A')
$$
which is applies here, since $A$ and $A'$ describe a set of mutually exclusive scenarios that form the whole space. So the object you want to calculate is:

$$P(A|B) = \frac{P(B|A) P(A)}{P(B|A) P(A) + P(B|A') P(A')}.$$

We are given:

$P(A) = 0.00207$. That is, the probability of having lime disease. Of course this implies that $P(A') = 0.99793.$

Also, the false positive rate is 0.03. That means that, given that a person doesn't have lime disease, the probability of getting a positive test is 0.03. That is, $P(B|A') = 0.03$.

The probability of getting a negative test, given that the patient *does* have lime disease is 0.063. That is, $P(B'|A) = 0.063$. Thus, the probability of getting a positive test for a lime disease patient (the only other possibility given the patient has lime disease) is $P(B|A) = 0.937$.

Comment: Wait, so I was incorrect? Why would we write $P(A)P(B|A)$ in the numerator and denominator instead of $P(B)P(A|B)$? What you wrote reads to me as 'Probability of $A$ happening and probability of $B$ happening if $A$ happens'. Why would we want that?

Comment: Bayes' Theorem states that (and I like this formulation better): $$P(A|B) P(B) = P(A \text{ and } B) = P(B|A) P(A).$$ So our numerators are equal. But at least with mine, you can actually calculate the fields. Also, look at your denominator. In order to make your statement consistent your denominator should be equal to P(B), but it isn't.

Comment: OKay, I took away my previous comments as I now think I understand Bayes' Theorem. HOWEVER, I do not understand how I can translate the theorem from my tree-diagram. Could you assist with that?

Comment: [Bayes' Thrm tree diagram](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/61/Bayes_theorem_tree_diagrams.svg/620px-Bayes_theorem_tree_diagrams.svg.png) whaaaaaat. How is this true. Argh.

Comment: Start with the other tree (i.e. start the split by $A$ and $A'$). It will be much easier to fill in those fields because you are already given $P(A)$, $P(B|A')$, and $P(B'|A)$. Using applications of Bayes Theorem and the law of total probability, you can fill in the rest of the fields. Then go back to your original tree. Using Bayes Theorem you can immediately fill in the right ends, and then through applications of Bayes and total probability you can fill the rest of that.

Comment: But, don't we have to test for LD first? i.e., split by B and B'? I think i'm just going to have to accept this by proof of authority.

Comment: I UNDERSTAND. I AM ALL THE UNDERSTAND YES FINALLY

Comment: I TOO HAVE ARRIVED!!!